# PHP, navegador no muestra "echo" concreto

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Muy buenas, cuando mi login se realiza correctamente, mi navegador no muestra mensaje alguno, sin embargo, cuando el login no se realiza bien si se muestra tanto el mensaje
"No ingreso", como el script de error, adjunto el código.

Gracias

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn) 
{
    die("No hay conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nombre = $_POST["txtusuario"];
$pass = $_POST["txtpassword"];

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = '".$nombre."' and password = '".$pass."'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($nr == 1)
{
    //header("Location: pagina.html");
    echo "Bienvenido:" .$nombre;
}
else if ($nr == 0) 
{
    //header("Location: login.html");
    echo "No ingreso"; 
    //echo "<script> alert('Error');window.location= 'login.html' </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Has revisado que el dato cuando ingresas correctamente sea el correcto? tanto el tipo como el valor

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido. Revisa pues, el contenido de `$nr` y `$query` para que puedas identificar qué puede estar sucediendo. Edita tu pregunta con la información que encutnres.

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, si que es correcto, de hecho el código es un ejercicio y está copiado tal cual, El VS Code no me detecta errores en el código y en la base de datos solo está creado un usuario para realizar el ejemplo. El caso es que lo hice hace unas semanas con otro pc, con windows , y no tuve problemas

Comment: Acabo de probar el código y no hay problemas , es funcional, hay que verificar el paso previo y los datos que llegan, podrías hacer un echo de tu consulta o poner `$nr = mysqli_query($conn, $query ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conn));` , para ver si ahí esta el error.

Comment: @rpaillao he probado a realizar "echo" y tampoco lo imprime, cuando no se realiza el login si, imprime el echo sin problema

Comment: podrias publicar la pagina donde tienes tu formulario de ingreso?.

Comment: Y estás seguro de que `$nr` SOLO vale 1, y no más?? A ver si vas a tener duplicados los datos que ingresas...

Comment: @rpaillao la pagina de donde estoy siguiendo los pasos es: https://vaidrollteam.blogspot.com/2019/11/crear-login-basico-con-html-php-xampp.html

Comment: @Benito-B solo he creado un usuario con una contraseña, siguiendo el ejemplo de la web tal cual

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré el fallo, en la creación de la base de datos le daba al botón incorrecto, se creaba el mismo usuario por duplicado y por eso no imprimía lo correcto. Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]